# Variable has different value in `if` statement

Tags: c++

In my class I declared `i`, as `private int i`.
In my one class function I declare `i = 0`, like this:

```
void Expression::tokenize()
{
    i = 0;
    cout<<"i before is:"<< i <<endl;

    strcpy(exp, expression.c_str());
    char *p = strtok(exp, " ");

    while (p != NULL)
    {
        if(strcmp(p, "+"))
        {
            cout<<"i after is:"<< i <<endl;
            ops[i] = *p;
        };

        p = strtok(NULL, " ");
    };
}
```

The "i before" has the value 0, but the "i after" has some totally different value.

Comment: why do you use C functions while it C++ and you can use std::string  and standard algorithms for everything you need?

Comment: The question is not clear

Comment: The variable i is probably accessed by some other thread/function since it's declaration scope is larger that the function.

Comment: And I have not idea about variable expression. Could you provide cleaner code sample?

Comment: did you make sure that exp is large enough to contain expression.c_str()? otherwise you might have undefined behavior right there.

Comment: show us `exp`, `expression`, and `ops`

Comment: I guess the overflow of `exp` occurred and it ate the `i`

Comment: I'm pretty sure the memory is corrupted (which can happen if you deal with pointers), so the problem is not the variable i, but something else in the code

Comment: Use visual studio and put a watch to thevariable (or with valgrind if you use GCC)

Comment: You're probably overriding `i` when you assign `ops[i] = ...`. You probably never allocate this array properly.

Comment: As others have said, `exp` is to small. Ditch the C-style "strings" and work exclusively with `std::string`.

Comment: The problem was, that I did not declare the size of exp. Thanks.

Comment: @ikh wow. that is something :-)

Comment: @paper006 ..so you should use `std::string` in C++, not c-string.

Comment: Where is your testcase?

Comment: @Nabin manual memory management is *always* bugged >o<

Comment: @paper006 could you please paste your complete code here. From the given function, everything looks fine. This may  be the case of overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You've apparently already found the specific problem (and presumably at least believe you've fixed it).

This is more about how to avoid such problems to start with. You're splitting a string into tokens separated by one or more spaces. In C++, you can do that quite a bit more cleanly using code something like this:

```
std::istringstream buffer(expression);

std::string token;
while (buffer >> token) { 
    if (token == "+")
        ops.push_back(token);
```

You can clean that up still a step further using a standard algorithm:

```
std::istringstream buffer(expression);

std::copy_if(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(buffer),
             std::istream_ierator<std::string>(),
             std::back_inserter(ops),
             [](std::string const &s) { return s=="+"; });
```

I am taking a little bit of a guess about your intent here. As it is right now, your code stores every `+` into `ops[0]`, since you never increment `i`, but I'd guess that's an oversight or a simplification for posting, and you really intended to store them into successive locations. Likewise, I'd guess you really want to store any operator, so you probably really want a lambda expression more like this:

```
[](std::string const &s) { return s.find_first_of("+-*/") != std::string::npos; }
```